# Query dimensions of main window

Tags: window

I am trying to setup my init files, and want a special set of dimensions for my main Emacs window. If I place my window wherever I want it, is there a way of querying Emacs as to the main window dimensions? I.e., is there a way of querying the value of the `top`, `left`, `width`, and `height` values of the main window as it is currently placed?

Comment: In Emacs, we use the word "frame" to mean the whole kitten kaboodle; whereas, "window" is within the "frame" and there can be many "windows".  Please edit your question (title and body) accordingly.  In addition, please specify your operating system -- other solutions may exist, e.g., an applescript on OSX to get frame coordinates, etc.

Comment: How about this [google search for "emacs window dimensions"](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=emacs+window+dimensions)?  Among the first hits are manual pages for [window sizes](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Window-Sizes.html) and [frame size and position](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Size-and-Position.html).

Comment: @Dan -- I don't believe any of those functions return frame coordinates on the OS desktop in pixels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's `(window-width)` and `(window-pixel-width)` (and the equivalent height functions) for getting the width in characters and pixels respectively.

There's also `(window-pixel-top)` and `(window-pixel-left)`.

I'm not really sure if these are what you're looking for.

I used `helm-apropos` to find these functions. There's also a built-in command to search functions: `M-x apropos RET window left RET`.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about `apropos`.